# get css from <style> as text for output

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

How can I grab entire `css` from `<style id="myId" type="text/css">` to push it into a `JSON` file?

**I am adding dynamically `css` to `<style>`, so in my `html` the style is empty.**

Tried with `$('#myId').text()`, `$('#myId').html()` with no luck.

I need for this type of output:

```
function addRule(selector, rules) {
      var stylesheet = document.getElementById('myId');
      if (stylesheet) {
        stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;
        if (stylesheet.addRule) {
          for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; ++i) {
            stylesheet.addRule(selector[i], rules);
          }
        } else if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
          stylesheet.insertRule(selector.join(',') + ' { ' + rules + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
        }
      }
}
function pushToJson(){
  item {}
  dataCSS = []
  item ["myCSS"] = '?????'; 
  // here I need the css 
  // eg: "h1 {margin:0;} .title {padding:10px 0;}"
  dataCSS.push(item);
}
addRule(['.title, h2'], 'color:red;');
```

Any help?

Comment: `.text()` seems to work just fine for me.

Comment: Try with `document.getElementById('myId').innerHTML`

Comment: wasn't sure until now, that if you add dynamic css into style, you can't grab it with `.html()`, or I am wrong?

Comment: Exactly *how* are you *"adding dynamically"* css to `<style>`?

Comment: sorry, updated my question again with my function used to add css

Comment: Can't you just call the `pushToJson()` function after `addRule()` function executes?

Comment: I use multiple `addRule()` functions, can't call it each time..

Comment: Use the equivalent get property `stylesheet.cssRules`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of `stylesheet.addRule` and `stylesheet.insertRule` is

```
stylesheet.cssRules
```

Here's an example using `.cssRules` that ignores all the inherited and "actual" css that's applied and reads only the rules in your `style` tag

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet for more info.

```js
function addRule(selector, rules) {
  var stylesheet = document.getElementById('myId');
  if (stylesheet) {
    stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;
    if (stylesheet.addRule) {
      for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; ++i) {
        stylesheet.addRule(selector[i], rules);
      }
    } else if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
      stylesheet.insertRule(selector.join(',') + ' { ' + rules + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
}

addRule(['.title, h2'], 'color:red;');
addRule(['body h2'], 'font-weight:normal;');

function pushToJson() {
  var stylesheet = document.getElementById('myId');
  if (stylesheet) {
    stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;
    for(var i = 0; i<stylesheet.cssRules.length;++i) {
        // Do the JSON magic here
        console.dir(
            stylesheet.cssRules[i].selectorText 
            + " : " 
            + stylesheet.cssRules[i].style.cssText)
    }
  }
}

pushToJson();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="myId" type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
</style>
<h2>Title</h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code grabs the entire code from the specified `style` tag. You can then store it inside a new variable or do whatever you want with it.

```js
var newJSON = {};

function addRule(selector, rules) {
  var stylesheet = document.getElementById('myId');
  if (stylesheet) {
    stylesheet = stylesheet.sheet;
    if (stylesheet.addRule) {
      for (var i = 0; i < selector.length; ++i) {
        stylesheet.addRule(selector[i], rules);
      }
    } else if (stylesheet.insertRule) {
      stylesheet.insertRule(selector.join(',') + ' { ' + rules + ' }', stylesheet.cssRules.length);
    }
  }
  pushToJson();
}

function pushToJson() {
  newJSON = $('#myId').html();
  console.log(newJSON);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style id="myId" type="text/css">
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that, I am adding css dynamically into `<style>`

Comment: @Adrian What do you mean by `dynamically`? You are importing another css stylesheet or using an asynchronous call?

Comment: Updated my question, wasn't sure that adding later css into my style, can be a problem when I want to grab it :(

Comment: `addRule()` function is executed as first function, right? It fills up the stylesheet with css properties and **then** you want to export it into JSON?

Comment: yes, I run multiple `addRule()` functions and **at the end** I run JSON save

Comment: @Adrian I've edited my post. You can call the `pushToJson()` function with every `addRule()` call. It will replace the `newJSON` variable with new data, after it's filled with new css rules.

Comment: still not getting css from `addRule()` function

Comment: You question is about how to export stylesheet into JSON and actually I've helped you with it. Another thing is the functionality of `addRule()` function and seems like this is a topic for another, brand new question. But I will  try to do something with it.

Comment: I just created a [fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/templatetuners/0tec1d1c/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
$('#myId').css()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>

  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <style>
    #myname{
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>    


//This Line will yield you the style innerHTML

console.log(document.head.innerHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myId'),
    style = window.getComputedStyle(element);
jsonStyle = JSON.stringify(style);
```

Comment: With this I am getting a lot of css, don't know from where. Sample: `{"0":"animation-delay","1":"animation-direction","2":"animation-duratio..`

Comment: You take all of style of this element include inherited

Comment: if you need to take just itself try use this code:

var style = document.getElementById('myId').style,
jsonStyle = JSON.stringify(style);

Comment: again is getting strange css  `{\"alignContent\":\"\",\"alignItems\":\"\",\"alignSelf\":\"\",\"alignmentBasel..`

Comment: did this maybe it will help [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/templatetuners/0tec1d1c/1/)